# Dynamic column name compared with value in where clause using MyBatis

Tags: java, spring, orm, mybatis, ibatis

Is it possible to use something like

```
SEARCH_QUERY = "select * from info where #{columnName}=\"#{columnValue}\"";
```

using MyBatis 3 ?

The columnName needs to be dynamic.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use syntax like `#columnValue` mybatis will create prepared statement and will bind the variable for you. This has several consequences:

1. you don't need to put quotes around `#columnValue`
2. you don't need to escape values passed
3. `#` can only be used where the parameter in JDBC query is allowed. So you can't use it to generate dynamic column name

If you want to generate dynamic query use `$columnName` instead. The complete query would look like:

```
select * from info where ${columnName}=#{columnValue}
```

Important thing to remember is that `${columnName}` is put to query verbatim very much like string concatenation if you would use JDBC directly so it is vulnerable to the SQL injection if `columnName` is something provided by user.

Comment: But is it safe? since `$` is not using prepared statement.

Comment: If the piece of the query provided by user it is not safe the same way it is not safe to use string concatenation in JDBC.